# Using printer name Adobe PDF

Tags: printing

I have looked everywhere for this solution. The code below allows me to print to the printer, Adobe PDF, but what I want to do is automate the file name save as screen with a generic name and in a specific folder. For example, the file would be saved to `C:\temp\tmpResize.pdf` and I am having problems there.

```
var params = this.getPrintParams();
params.interactive=params.constants.interactionLevel.silent;
params.pageHandling=params.constants.handling.none;
params.fileName =  "/c/temp/tmpResize.pdf";    
params.printerName="Adobe PDF"
this.print(params);
```

Thanks for your help.